# How to Use html iframe in Bootstrap Column

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

Good day. 
I want to use iframe in bootstrap column in order to display newspaper.  In left “col-md-4” Newspaper name will remain and in right “col-md-8” will newspaper will display because of using iframe. Would you like to edit my code or describe the to implement the system.

```
<section id="blog-area">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="news-paper-Name">
                <p>Newspaper Name Goes here</p>
                <p>Newspaper Name Goes here</p>
                <p>Newspaper Name Goes here</p>
                <p>Newspaper Name Goes here</p>
                <p>Newspaper Name Goes here</p>
                <p>Newspaper Name Goes here</p>
                <p>Newspaper Name Goes here</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="display">
            <h5> Selected or Browsing News paper will show here</h5>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>      
</div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you use iframe the problem is it is not responsive, which goes against the idea of bootstrap.

Comment: I have seen a such type of website

Comment: May be they have written some jquery which will detect the div width, height change event and then recalculate the width and height and apply to its iframe. I cant think of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code this may help you.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="blog-area">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="news-paper-Name">
                <iframe class="nfg320x210" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://www.gooplusplus.com/news-topic.html?h#TITLE"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="display">
            <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="320"
      src="http://www.gooplusplus.com/dark-topic-head.html?h&ned=in&hl=hi# &#2361;&#2367;&#2306;&#2342;&#2368;&#160; (india)"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>      
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I asked When I select Newspaper name then news paper will display  in col-md-8. This system will develop

Comment: No, this code does not resize the iframe to the size of the containing column.  Your right-side iframe is sized by width="320" , not by the width of the column (col-md-6).  The left side is sized to the default size of an iframe, regardless of the width of the column.  I think Reddy's comment is correct, one would have to listen for resize events to make a responsive iframe inside bootstrap.